# How to sort a dictionary in ascending order of values?

Tags: swift, dictionary

how can I sort a dictionary in ascending order of values?

I have something like this :

```
["user1": 3764, "user5": 23, "user87": 875, "user21": 54987, ... ]
```

And I would like to get a dictionary ranked in ascending order of its values, like this :

```
["user5": 23, "user87": 875, "user1": 3764, "user21": 54987, ...]
```

Comment: As has been discussed here countless times, dictionaries have no order.

Comment: Dictionaries guarantee no order (in memory), but there are applications where an ordered dict is useful. Depending on your final goal, you could take a look a `OrderedDict` or write a `class` around `dict` that gives you ordered output in the way you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
let userRankDict = ["user1": 3764, "user5": 23, "user87": 875, "user21": 54987]
let sortedUserRankDict = userRankDict.sorted{ $0.value < $1.value }
print(sortedUserRankDict)
```

Sorted userRankDict:

> [(key: "user5", value: 23), (key: "user87", value: 875), (key: "user1", value: 3764), (key: "user21", value: 54987)]